# extjs chart doesn' t show up

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

New on extjs chart.

I am having an extjs area chart, I got the store, model, ok, but the chart is not showing up at all, nothing, I have no idea where the problem is:

```
var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['date', 'ged', 'watt', 'sicomor'],
    data: [{
            "date": 20-10-2014,
            "ged": 52,
            "watt": 21,
            "sicomor": 18
        }, {
            "date": 21 - 10 - 2014,
            "ged": 24,
            "watt": 62,
            "sicomor": 14
        }, {
            "date": 22-10-2014,
            "ged": 41,
            "watt": 69,
            "sicomor": 25
        }]
});


Ext.define("dashboard.view.HrsWorkedChart", {
    extend: "Ext.chart.Chart",
    alias: "widget.hrsworkedchart",

        style: 'background:#fff',
        animate: true,
        store: store1,

        legend: {
            position: 'right'
        },

        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            minimum: 0,
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['watt', 'ged', 'sicomor'],
            title: 'Nombre documents en retard',
            minorTickSteps: 1,
            grid: {
                odd: {
                    opacity: 1,
                    fill: '#ddd',
                    stroke: '#bbb',
                    'stroke-width': 0.5
                }
            }
        }, {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['date'],
            title: 'Jours'
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            axis: 'left',
            xField: 'name',
            yField: ['watt', 'ged', 'sicomor'],
        }]

});

Ext.application({
    name: 'AreaChart',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'hrsworkedchart'})
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPEEv/700/)

Can you help me out.

Cheers a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write all your code inside the `launch` method of your `Ext.application` to make sure that ExtJS is loaded and ready to be used. You should also create your Viewport, for this you could use the `autoCreateViewport` method or simply add an `Ext.create` to the end of your launch method.

This should work:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AreaChart',
    launch: function () {
        var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['date', 'ged', 'watt', 'sicomor'],
            data: [{
                "date": 20-10-2014,
                "ged": 52,
                "watt": 21,
                "sicomor": 18
            }, {
                "date": 21 - 10 - 2014,
                "ged": 24,
                "watt": 62,
                "sicomor": 14
            }, {
                "date": 22-10-2014,
                "ged": 41,
                "watt": 69,
                "sicomor": 25
            }]
        });


        Ext.define("dashboard.view.HrsWorkedChart", {
            extend: "Ext.chart.Chart",
            alias: "widget.hrsworkedchart",

            style: 'background:#fff',
            animate: true,
            store: store1,

            legend: {
                position: 'right'
            },

            axes: [{
                type: 'Numeric',
                minimum: 0,
                position: 'left',
                fields: ['watt', 'ged', 'sicomor'],
                title: 'Nombre documents en retard',
                minorTickSteps: 1,
                grid: {
                    odd: {
                        opacity: 1,
                        fill: '#ddd',
                        stroke: '#bbb',
                        'stroke-width': 0.5
                    }
                }
            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['date'],
                title: 'Jours'
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'name',
                yField: ['watt', 'ged', 'sicomor'],
            }]

        });

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'hrsworkedchart'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you'd better define the view and data (maybe model as well) in separate files.

for your case:

```
//create a file under dashborad.store.HrsWorkedChart.js
Ext.define("dashboard.store.HrsWorkedChart", { //config options });

//create a file under dashboard.view.HrsWorkedChart.js
Ext.define("dashboard.view.HrsWorkedChart", { 
......
store: dashboard.store.HrsWorkedChart,
......
});
```

then you load your viewport as Guiherme said.